# Stuck on a continuity proof of a special piecewise function.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

How would I show that the following function is continuous at $x = 0$?
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\begin{cases}
          \exp(-1/x^2) \quad &\text{if} \, x\ne0 \\
          0 \quad &\text{if} \, x=0\\
     \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

I tried using the $\epsilon$ - $\delta$ definition of continuity but got absolutely nowhere.
Any tips or help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I do not see all that much difference between proving with $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ that, say, $x^2+5x+3$ is continuous at $0$ and proving it for $f$. If anything, the former is harder.

Comment: Showing what you've tried might help ppl answer your question.

Comment: I ended up writing up something better than what I originally did (which wasnt even worth posting). The stuff that other people have answered with is probably better than mine, but I'll still write what I did in a comment below this.

Answer (score 1):

The epsilon definition looks like a good approach. Given $\varepsilon$, you're looking for $\delta$ such that $\exp(-1/x^2)$ is less than $\varepsilon$ whenever $|x|<\delta$.

So you want to solve the inequality

$$
e^{-1/x^2} < \varepsilon
$$

for $x$, which will tell you your $\delta$. In doing so, keep in mind that the logarithm is strictly monotone, and that $\log \varepsilon$ is negative if $\varepsilon<1$ (which you can assume without loss of generality).

Answer (score 0):

**By the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition.** For all $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta(\epsilon)=\sqrt{-\log(\min\{1,\epsilon\})}$ such that if $|x-0|<\sqrt{-\log(\min\{1,\epsilon\})}$ then $|\exp{\frac{-1}{x^2}}-0|<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)$ is continuous in $x = 0$, then

$
\forall_{\epsilon > 0} \; \exists_{\delta > 0} \; \forall_{x < \delta} \; |x| < \delta \implies |f(x)| < \epsilon
$

Observation: since $\forall_{x} f(x) \geq 0$, we just have to check if $f(x) < \epsilon$. Furthermore $f(-x) = f(x)$.

Now suppose $\epsilon > 0$; WLOG $\epsilon < 1$.
Choose $\delta = \sqrt{-\frac{1}{\log \epsilon}}$

Since $\epsilon < 1$, $\log \epsilon < 0$. Hence the square root is well defined.

With $|x| < \delta$ we obtain

1. If $x = 0$, then $f(x) = 0 < \epsilon$.
2. Else $f(x) = \exp(-\frac{1}{x^2}) < \exp(\delta) = 
    \exp(-\frac{1}{(\sqrt{-\frac{1}{\log \epsilon}})^2}) =
    \exp(-\frac{1}{-\frac{1}{\log \epsilon}}) =
    \exp(\log \epsilon) = \epsilon$,

which shows the desired inequality.